# Using EntityFramework Include with OfType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

In my query i need to include (to avoid lazy loading) a list of entities.

```
query.Include(x => x.ActionValues.Select(a => a.ActionValueDetails));
```

this works without any problems but in some cases i need another eager loaded property of *ActionValueDetail*. ActionValueDetail is a base class of many other implementations of it. My code looks like this for these cases:

```
query.Include(t => t.ActionValues.Select(a => a.ActionValueDetails.OfType<ActionValueDetailSpecial>().Select(d => d.SpecialDetail)));
```

But this always throws an exception.

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Using lazy-loading or projection is not an option for me in this case. We need this for very large exports to ensure all data is loaded before we're writing into a stream.

Any help would be great!

Comment: You can't conditionally eager load things. You get them all or you get none. Perhaps you can filter the results later on in a select?

Comment: I don't want to filter the 'ActionValueDetails'. Some of the ActionValueDetail implementations have some further related entities. In some cases i need to eager load these related entites. But i think i have to use another strategy to achieve this. But thanks.anyway :)

Comment: `OfType` is filtering ;-)

Comment: yeah ok you're right! :) sorry

Comment: I think you can solve it by making .Union() of two separate queries, one which loads all the objects, which is the one you already have, and a second one which explicitly includes the ActionValueDetailSpecial, and the realted property.